# why filtering is not working in angular when type to user input?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  _userinput:string='';
  filteritems:any[];
  items:any[] = [
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2'
    }

  ]
  name = 'Angular 6';


get userinput(){
   return this._userinput;
}

set userinput(val){
  console.log('val',val);
 this._userinput = val;
 this.filteritems = this.items.filter((item)=>{
   return item.name.indexOf(val)!=-1
 })

 console.log(this.filteritems);
}
ngOnInit(){
  this.filteritems = this.items;
}

}
```

**could you please tell me why filtering is not working** I have one `input` field I want to filter list when I typed on `input` field

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wbd1q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

can you please provide other or best way to filter this list currently I am doing 2 way binding so I think it is not a best way to implement filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is you do is using a Filter pipe as follows,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return items;
   return items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(term) !== -1);
    }
  }
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example-vtjakt?file=app%2FfilterPipe.ts)**

Comment: why you say its best? Angular team removed Filter pipe because of a poor performance - https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 1):

Because it expects exact match - type the whole name, for ex. "Test 1" and it will provide filtered results.

You probably want to check if substring exists. Change this:

```
return item.name.indexOf(val)!=-1
```

To:

```
return item.name.includes(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work  slightly better no type casing required

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'filter'
    })
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(items: any, term: any): any {
        if (term === undefined) return items;
       return items.filter(item => (item.name).toLowerCase().indexOf((term).toLowerCase()) !== -1);
        }

  }
```